# Angular slider with 3 points

Tags: html, angular

Is there a straightforward method for incorporating a slider with three points? I'm looking for something similar to the slider with a range, as demonstrated in this example: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview#slider-range.

Despite my efforts in searching online and asking ChatGBT I haven't been able to find a solution. As a newcomer to programming, I find myself unable to implement such a feature independently completly from scratch. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not an Angular component, but I think it can be helpful for you 
https://embed.plnkr.co/XJyMrxVgFixCKkUnwUTA/preview

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/home?  ngx-slider does have issue working with Angular 16+, its fork ngx-slider-v2 works fine with Angular 16+.